# Wordpress editor, change code wrap (bbpress?)

Tags: tags, editor, code, bbpress

I am developing a theme and using jquery prettify to style code tags. Sofar I love prettify, and for the most part wordpress is cooperating.

When text is wrapped in `<code>` tags everything works dandy. But on certain editors, and the bbpress topic / reply / edit , editor the code is wrapped in the the little dash marks just like on these forums, and sometimes the code gets all mangled.

What I am looking to do is force every editor on my wordpress install , or atleast the `code` buttons on the editor to wrap code in  tags instead of the little dash marks. I have looked at some filters but sofar i do not see how to change the output or behavior of the tiny mce fancy editor buttons thats standard with wordpress.

Thanks for any direction or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_footer','ravs_codeTag_fix');
function ravs_codeTag_fix(){
    if ( bbp_use_wp_editor() ) :
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready( function() {

            /* Use <code> instead of backticks for the Code button in the editor */
            if ( typeof( edButtons ) !== 'undefined' ) {
                edButtons[110] = new QTags.TagButton( 'code', 'code', '<code>', '</code>', 'c' );
                QTags._buttonsInit();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

**Note:**

bbpress plugin overwrites the code button behaviour ( of wordpress editor ) by putting some script in head.You can find this script in `bbpress->templates->default->bbpress-functions.php` online 219

**Updated:**

1).If you want to customize wordpress editor then you can explore it by going throw [WordPress QuickTags API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Quicktags_API) ([quicktags.js](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js)) and [Tinymce WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE).These documention also have good tutorial link which guide you practically.

2).You can use WordPress Plugin [AddQuicktag](http://wordpress.org/plugins/addquicktag/screenshots/) for editing WordPress Editor.This plugin make it easy, Quicktags add to the html - and visual-editor.. It is possible to ex- and import your Quicktags.

**Edited:**

paste below code in `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'bbp_new_topic_pre_content',  'ravs_bbp_code_trick', 10);
add_filter( 'bbp_new_reply_pre_content',  'ravs_bbp_code_trick', 10);
add_filter( 'bbp_new_forum_pre_content',  'ravs_bbp_code_trick', 10);
add_filter( 'bbp_edit_topic_pre_content',  'ravs_bbp_code_trick', 10);
add_filter( 'bbp_edit_topic_pre_content',  'ravs_bbp_code_trick', 10);
add_filter( 'bbp_edit_forum_pre_content',  'ravs_bbp_code_trick', 10);
function ravs_bbp_code_trick( $content ){
    $pattrens[0]='/<code>/';
    $pattrens[1]='/<\/code>/';
    $content = preg_replace( '/\`/','backtick_place', $content );
    $content = preg_replace( $pattrens,'`', $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('bbp_get_topic_content','ravs_bbp_prevent_trick',51);
add_filter('bbp_get_reply_content','ravs_bbp_prevent_trick',51);
add_filter('bbp_get_form_forum_content','ravs_bbp_prevent_trick',51);
function ravs_bbp_prevent_trick($content){
    $content = preg_replace( '/backtick_place/','`', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: excellent, I will implement this and accept the answer if it works when I get a chance. If possible could you describe the ed buttons[] array and the QTags.TagButton() functon briefly so I can attempt to implement my own solutions in the future?

Comment: Answer updated, check it.Code in answer is test with bbpress.`ed_buttons` is a `object` while `QTags` is function.

Comment: The function now correctly changes the output of the code button to be <code> but now wordpress, or bbpress more so does not display the information correctly. When using backticks the code is displayed fine, but when using <code> bbpress seems to inject closing tags in wierd places breaking it all up, or it just not preserve the code and outputs it as if it were html (testing with html code)

Comment: Ive accepted your answer, as it does what i asked, but does not function how I wish it functioned...

Comment: wihthout seeing your test it's difficult to tell what's wrong.do you have live test site?

Comment: http://oq.publicvent.org/forums/forum/website-feedback-suggestions/ . This is my live site. Ive implemented the function here so you can see it in action. Please crete any number of topics / replys in that sub forum there.

Comment: answer updated.please make sure, don't put `code` tag inside `code` tag.test it with raw html and php code

Comment: Well the code im most concerned about at the moment is lua, it appears lua uses backticks sometimes for certain things, and sometimes my users post lua code on the site, and if there is a backtick in the code then it breaks the code wrap... but your solution does work nicely sofar with html and php.

Comment: create a topic with lua code and give me a link.

Comment: http://oq.publicvent.org/forums/topic/title/ you can see here how the backticks were replaced with the code tags. ie `function backtick functionname backtick` is now `function code functionname code`

Comment: edit the `Edited` part of answer please replace the code and test again.

Comment: The backtick_place inject works, but now there is no code tags output when the reply / topic is rendered. ie: the code tags dont show, its output as pure text

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9707/discussion-between-ravs-and-ronburgundy)